# Pyinstaller stopping in terminal and won't continue

Tags: python, pyinstaller

When I run pyinstaller through the terminal it stops and shows a few random letters and a ':' . If anything is typed after the ':' it says 'wrong'. This is my first time using pyinstaller and cannot seem to get it right, and its probably something simple I just can't find. The code is just a GUI that when a button is clicked the corresponding code runs a cheat code for a game, which I hopefully posted right. There is also a screenshot of the terminal.
[terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug6Uz.png)

Update:
Uninstalled pyinstaller and reinstalled it goes past the previous problem but now I'm getting a  subprocess.TimeoutExpired. Here is a copy of the Command Prompt[Command Prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9wGh.png)

```py
import time
import keyboard
import win32gui
import pygetwindow as gw
import tkinter as tk

def get_window():
    '''Focus the game window.'''
    win = str(gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Age of Empires: Definitive Edition'))
    hwnd = int(win[18:-2])
    win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)

def all_cheats():
    '''Run all resource cheats multiple times.'''
    get_window()
    codes = ['coinage','woodstock','quarry','pepperoni pizza']
    for t in range(5): # Change range for more entries.
        for x in range(len(codes)):
            time.sleep(.2)
            keyboard.send('enter')
            time.sleep(.2)
            keyboard.write(codes[x])
            time.sleep(.2)
            keyboard.send('enter')


def cheat(code):
    '''Run cheats 5 times.'''
    get_window()
    for t in range(5): # Change range for more entries. 
        time.sleep(.2)
        keyboard.send('enter')
        time.sleep(.2)
        keyboard.write(code)
        time.sleep(.2)
        keyboard.send('enter')

def single_cheat(code):
    '''Run cheats that only require one entry.'''
    get_window()
    time.sleep(.2)
    keyboard.send('enter')
    time.sleep(.2)
    keyboard.write(code)
    time.sleep(.2)
    keyboard.send('enter')

def steroids_cheat(code):
    '''Run steroid cheat twice, on and off'''
    get_window()
    for t in range(2):
        time.sleep(.2)
        keyboard.send('enter')
        time.sleep(.2)
        keyboard.write(code)
        time.sleep(.2)
        keyboard.send('enter')



window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Age of Empire Cheats")


#Buttons for multiple entries
btn_all = tk.Button(window,text="ALL",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: all_cheats(),bg='yellow',fg='black')
btn_all.grid(row=0, column=0)

btn_coin = tk.Button(window,text="GOLD",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: cheat('coinage'),bg='#00FFFF',fg='black')
btn_coin.grid(row=0, column=1)


btn_food = tk.Button(window,text="FOOD",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: cheat('pepperoni pizza'),bg='#00FFFF',fg='black')
btn_food.grid(row=0, column=2)

btn_wood = tk.Button(window,text="WOOD",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: cheat('woodstock'),bg='#00FFFF',fg='black')
btn_wood.grid(row=0, column=3)

btn_stone = tk.Button(window,text="STONE",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: cheat('quarry'),bg='#00FFFF',fg='black')
btn_stone.grid(row=0, column=4)

btn_photon = tk.Button(window,text="PHOTON",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: cheat('photon man'),bg='#800000',fg='white')
btn_photon.grid(row=1, column=0)

btn_bdad = tk.Button(window,text="BIG DADDY",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: cheat('bigdaddy'),bg='#800000',fg='white')
btn_bdad.grid(row=1, column=1)

btn_emc = tk.Button(window,text="E=MC2",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: cheat('e=mc2 trooper'),bg='#800000',fg='white')
btn_emc.grid(row=1, column=2)

btn_bb= tk.Button(window,text="BABY",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: cheat('pow'),bg='#800000',fg='white')
btn_bb.grid(row=1, column=3)

# Buttons for single entry
btn_prst = tk.Button(window,text="PRIEST",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: single_cheat('hoyohoyo'),bg='#008080',fg='#800080')
btn_prst.grid(row=2, column=0)

btn_strd = tk.Button(window,text="STEROIDS",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: steroids_cheat('steroids'),bg='red',fg='black')
btn_strd.grid(row=2, column=1)

btn_ct = tk.Button(window,text="BIG BERTHA",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: single_cheat('big bertha'),bg='#008080',fg='#800080')
btn_ct.grid(row=2, column=2)

btn_icb = tk.Button(window,text="ICBM",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: single_cheat('icbm'),bg='#008080',fg='#800080')
btn_icb.grid(row=2, column=3)

btn_charc = tk.Button(window,text="FAST CHARIOT ARCHER",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: single_cheat('upsidflintmobile'),bg='#008080',fg='#800080')
btn_charc.grid(row=2, column=4)

btn_kr = tk.Button(window,text="DRAGONS",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: single_cheat('king arthur'),bg='#008080',fg='#800080')
btn_kr.grid(row=3, column=0)

btn_mp = tk.Button(window,text="REVEAL MAP",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: single_cheat('reveal map'),bg='blue',fg='white')
btn_mp.grid(row=3, column=1)

btn_nf = tk.Button(window,text="NO FOG",relief=tk.RAISED,command=lambda: single_cheat('no fog'),bg='blue',fg='white')
btn_nf.grid(row=3, column=2)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey there's no screenshot of the terminal.

Comment: The https link at the bottom of the post is the terminal picture. Link is https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug6Uz.png if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue.
Created a virtual environment using:

```
python -m venv name_of_environment
```

Activated it:

```
name_of_environment\Scripts\activate
```

Then

```
pip install name_of_packages
```

(all of them)
After all installed ran pyinstaller:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --icon=name.ico name_of_script.py
```

Once it finished, the .exe was in the dist folder

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.